# Proving that the set of all invertible diagonal matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ is a path connected subset of $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$

Tags: general-topology, matrices, determinant, path-connected

> Prove that the set of all invertible diagonal matrices $n\times n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is a subset path connected of $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$.

Writing $D$ for the set of all invertible diagonal matrices $n\times n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and given any $A,B\in D$, i must exhibit a path $f:[0,1]\rightarrow D$ such that $f$ is interely inside $D$. But this is really non-intuitive when talking about matrices. The only function that i can think of is the determinant function, but i don't know how to proceed with this idea. And also, since every $A\in D$ is invertible, its diagonal does not contain any $0$, and also i don't know how to apply this observation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to modify modify every entry on the diagonal from its old value in $A$ to the new one in $B$ without passing zero, e.g. one after the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $C(\lambda)=\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B$. A polynomial $|C(\lambda)|=0$ has only finitely many roots,
so there exists a path $p:[0,1]\to\Bbb C$ such that $p(0)=0$, $p(1)=1$ and 
$|C(p(t))|\ne 0$ for each $t\in [0,1]$. Then the path $C(p(t))$ connects $A$ and $B$ in $D$.